# referencing indices in boot function

Tags: r

I have a large dataset (DF), a subset of which looks like this:

```
Site    Event   HardwareID  Species Day1    Day2    Day3    Day4    Day5    Day6    
1       1       16_11       x       0       0       0       0       0       0   
1       1       29_11       y       0       0       6       2       0       1       
1       1       36_11       d       0       0       0       0       0       1       
1       1       41_11       y       0       0       2       4       1       1                
1       1       41_11       x       0       0       0       0       0       1            
1       1       58_11       a       0       0       1       0       0       0             
1       1       62_11       y       0       0       0       1       0       0           
1       1       62_11       z       0       0       0       0       0       0           
1       1       62_11       x       0       0       0       0       0       1            
2       1       40_AR       b       0       0       0       0       0       0           
2       1       12_11       z       0       0       1       0       0       0
```

I'd like to examine the minimum number of HardwareIDs to produce the most Species over the shortest amount of time, by calculating species accumulation curves (which intrinsically incorporates the Days columns) for each HardwareID, at each different site, and boostrapping the HardwareID selection part (so, look at accumulation curves using two HardwareIDs, then 3, then 4 etc, at each site).

I have written a function to create species accumulation curves (using specaccum) for a subset of these, such as:

```
Sites<-subset(DF,DF$Site==1)
samples<-function (x) {               
              specurve_sample<-(ddply(Sites[,4:length(colnames(Sites))],"Species",numcolwise(sum)))
              specurve_sample<-specurve_sample[-1,]
              n<-specurve_sample$Species
              n<-drop.levels(n,reorder=FALSE)                   
              specurve_sample<-specurve_sample[,-1]
              specurve_sample <-t(specurve_sample)
              colnames(specurve_sample)<-n
              specurve_sample<-as.data.frame(specurve_sample)
              sample_k<-specaccum(specurve_sample)
              out<-rbind(sample_k$richness,sample_k$sd)
              outnames<-c("Richness","SD")
              st<-rep(Sites$Site[1],2)
              out<-as.data.frame(cbind(outnames,st,out))          
              colnames(out)<-c("label","site","Days")
              out
              }
```

The function works fine if I subset my data before hand, but the boostrapping part does not work. I know I need to create a function (x,j) but cannot figure out where to place the j in my function. Here is the rest of my code. Many thanks for any assistance. James

```
all_data<-c()
for (i in 1:length(unique(DF$Site))) {
Sites<-subset(DF,DF$Site==i)
boots<-boot(Sites,samples, strata=Sites$HardwareID,R=1000)   
all_data<-rbind(all_data,boots)
all_data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward way to do this is to create a function of `x` and `j` (as you have started to do), and have the first line of that function identify the relevant bootstrap subset from the whole collection, `bootsub <- x[j, ]`.  Then, you can refer to this subset, `bootsub` throughout the rest of the function, and you need not refer to `j` again.

In your case, you don't want your function to refer back to your original data frame, `Site`.  So, every where that you have `Site` in your function, change it to `bootsub`.  For example:

```
samples <- function(x, j) {
    bootsub <- x[j, ]
    specurve_sample <- (ddply(bootsub[, 4:length(colnames(bootsub))], "Species", numcolwise(sum)))
    specurve_sample <- specurve_sample[-1, ]
    n <- specurve_sample$Species
    n <- drop.levels(n, reorder=FALSE)                   
    specurve_sample <- specurve_sample[, -1]
    specurve_sample <- t(specurve_sample)
    colnames(specurve_sample) <- n
    specurve_sample <- as.data.frame(specurve_sample)
    sample_k <- specaccum(specurve_sample)
    out <- rbind(sample_k$richness, sample_k$sd)
    outnames <- c("Richness", "SD")
    st <- rep(bootsub$Site[1], 2)
    out <- as.data.frame(cbind(outnames, st, out))          
    colnames(out) <- c("label", "site", "Days")
    out
    }
```

...

A follow up to the first two comments below.  It's a little hard to troubleshoot without data, but this is my best guess.  It may be that you have an issue with your `subset()` function, because you use `i` as an index of unique sites in the `for()` loop, but then refer to `i` as the ***value*** of the site in the call to `subset()`.  Also, it is likely more efficient to run one call to `do.call()` after the `for()` loop, rather than multiple calls to `rbind()` inside the loop.  Give this untested code a try.

```
# vector of unique sites
usite <- unique(DF$Site)
# empty list in which to put the bootstrap results
alldatlist <- vector("list", length(usite))
# loop through every site separately, save the bootstrap replicates ($t)
for(i in 1:length(usite)) {
    Sites <- subset(DF, DF$Site==usite[i])
    alldatlist[[i]] <- boot(Sites, samples, strata=Sites$HardwareID, R=1000)$t
    }
# combine the list of results into a single matrix
all_data <- do.call(rbind, alldatlist)
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, It runs for a while and then I get Error in boot(Sites, samples, strata = Sites$HardwareID, R = 100) : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was't finished. Looks like I'm assigning the output wrong somehow, even when I run it without the loop,so:Sites<-subset(DF,DF$Site==1)? Is there anything like browser() where I can look at iterations inside the bootstrap? Otherwise, I don't know how to see where it isn't working. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @user3122022 I edited the answer to address your comments (see above).

Comment: many thanks,I think it was because in my samples() function I tried to get the boot function to spit out two variables (richness and sd), once I reduced it to one, it seemed to work.

Comment: @user3122022, If the answer works, perhaps you could accept it?

Comment: thanks for that, the do.call() especially seems to speed up the processing.

Comment: You're welcome.  The stackoverflow way to say "thank you" is by marking someone's answer as "accepted".